# How can I filter Fact with a Dimension?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, mdx

I use `SSAS` and `SQL Server 2008 R2`

I write this query and it works:

```
SELECT 
 [Measures].[Circulation Count] 
    ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Store]
where [Circulation Kind].[Circulation Code].&[1]
```

And result is : 362154.2154

But when I use `Filter` function my result is empty.

```
SELECT 
Filter(
    [Measures].[Circulation Count] 
         ,
    [Circulation Kind].[Circulation Code]
    = 
    [Circulation Kind].[Circulation Code].&[1]
)
    ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Store]
```

How can I filter my result with the `Filter` function?

Comment: I'm not sure that you would want to use the filter function like that. Typically, the filter function is used to filter a set of dimension members. For instance, filtering stores where sales is greater than $100000 last month. Are you just asking theoretically, or is there something more than this query that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you are trying to find a way to do this query without using the where clause, you could put the [Circulation Kind].[Circulation Code].&[1] on the ROWS axis. Or create a calculated member Sum([Measures].[Circulation Count], [Circulation Kind].[Circulation Code].&[1]) and then use that on columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After communication with @FrankPI i fond that is good :

```
With 
    Member X As 
       ( 
          [Measures].[Circulation Count] , 
          (
              [Circulation Kind].[Circulation Code].&[1]
          ) 
       )

Select 
    X On Columns
From <>
```

And in this method i can filter my `measure` with a `dimension`.

Comment: Actually, you could omit the inner parentheses, as what you really use is the tuple `([Measures].[Circulation Count] ,[Circulation Kind].[Circulation Code].&[1])`. Analysis Services is just tolerant and allows you to use these parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

What your `Filter` expression does is:

- Starting with the one element set consisting of the measure `[Measures].[Circulation Count]`.
- Then, from this set keep (= filter) the elements (= measures) where the **value** of `[Circulation Kind].[Circulation Code]` is the same as the **value** of `[Circulation Kind].[Circulation Code].&[1]`. Comparing an attribute and a member triggers an implicit type cast to make both the same type, in this case the attribute is converted to a member by implicitly applying the `DefaultMember` method. This means you compare the value of the default member (usually the `All` member) with the value of the member having key `1`. And, assuming there are more than one members in this attribute, this is probably always false.

Note that `=` compares the **values** on both sides, in this case, as the context sets the measure to `Circulation Count`, the value of `Circulation Count`. If you want to compare for member identity, you would have to use `IS` instead of `=`.

WHat does this mean for your statement? I am not sure why you do not want to use the `WHERE` clause, but as @mmarie stated, you could just move the `[Circulation Code]` from the `WHERE` axis to the rows axis:

```
SELECT 
 [Measures].[Circulation Count] 
    ON COLUMNS,
 [Circulation Kind].[Circulation Code].&[1]
    ON ROWS
FROM [Store]
```

And if you really, really want to use `Filter`, you could use:

```
SELECT 
 [Measures].[Circulation Count] 
    ON COLUMNS,
 Filter([Circulation Kind].[Circulation Code].Members as c,
        c.Current IS [Circulation Kind].[Circulation Code].&[1]
       )
    ON ROWS
FROM [Store]
```

Note the usage of `.Members` to explicitly convert the attribute to the set of its members, and the usage of `IS`, not `=`, in the last statement.

Comment: I want create a Member and in Member Syntax i can not use where!

Comment: Some things like this : With Member X As ( [Measures].[Circulation Count] , ([Circulation Kind].[Circulation Code].&[1]) )

Comment: In which context are you assuming you need the member syntax? Maybe what you need is a set, not a member.

Comment: @loup And what is the problem with using the syntax you described above (`With Member X As ( [Measures].[Circulation Count] , ([Circulation Kind].[Circulation Code].&[1]) )`)?